# How can I install qcl on OSX?

Tags: macos, gcc, compilation, homebrew, qcl

The answer to this question might be easy for some of you but I haven't been able to figure it out. There is very little information on this topic on the web, I guess it doesn't interest a lot of people.

I'm trying to install qcl on my mac. However, I have no clue how to do so. I know I should compile it in a certain way (through GCC?), but I don't know how.
Here's where the installation files are : http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/qcl.html

I also tried installing it through homebrew (brew install homebrew/science/qcl). But when I do so, I get an error when trying to run it (by typing qcl in the terminal). Here's the error in question :

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/qcl
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/qcl
Abort trap: 6
```

I'd really like to figure out a solution to the problem on my own but I guess my CS knowledge is insufficient. I need your help.

Thank you in advance for all your answers !

Comment: On macOS Sierra, running `brew install qcl` install a running version of qcl. Did you install xcode with `xcode-select --install`?